# iOS multiple notification permissions

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios-permissions

Are there two separate permissions for iOS notifications i.e. local and push? Is it possible that application will ask for both permissions?

I am asking as I've found two different messages:

- "AppName" would like to send you notifications. ...
- "AppName" would like to send you push notifications. ...

If there are two permissions, what are the possible cases.

- What if member rejects one of them?
- Does one permission includes second? I.e. "push notification" includes "notifications"?

Comment: I use one popup for my app with Push Notifications APNS or Local.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate support for Push Notifications then give permission by Accepting it for Push Notifications.

But if you want to integrate support for Local Notifications then you have accept it.

As after iOS 8 it requires for Local Notification to take permission from user.

> In iOS 8.0 and later, your application must register for user
>   notifications using -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]
>   before being able to schedule and present UILocalNotifications.

Comment: So just to confirm. I want both types then I will see two permission requests?

Comment: Ya , you have to accept both of them for particular service.

Comment: After accepting these permissions will they both appear in application settings? I haven's seen such situation. There are "notifications" only, no separate push/local.